# WPF, How to get the selected text in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selectedvalue

I am editing a textcell in a datagrid and I would like to get the selected text inside the datagrid cell text. Is there an event for it? The target is to find out the meaning of the selected text and show the ToolTip with the meaning. See the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X62v6.png)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgMeanings" Grid.Row="5" FontSize="16"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RowEditEnding="dgMeanings_RowEditEnding" PreviewKeyDown="dgMeanings_PreviewKeyDown" AddingNewItem="dgMeanings_AddingNewItem" Background="{Binding ButtonBackColor}" Foreground="{Binding TextForeColor}" SelectionChanged="txt_SelectionChanged" CellEditEnding="dgMeanings_CellEditEnding" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="#"  Binding="{Binding IORDER,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="30"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="LEVEL"  Binding="{Binding LEVEL,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="50"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="AS"  Binding="{Binding TYPE ,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="60" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="MEANING"  Binding="{Binding MEANING ,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="400" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="TRANSLATION"  Binding="{Binding TRANSLATION ,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="150" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="EXAMPLE"  Binding="{Binding EXAMPLE,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="400"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="EXAMPLE TRANSLATION"  Binding="{Binding EXAMPLE_TRANSLATION,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="400"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns >
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding LabelForeColor}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# Code**

```
private void dgMeanings_Clicked(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure at least 1 cell was selected
    if (dgMeanings.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {

        // Get text from cell by getting the cell content at the selected cell's index
        // Next, convert it to a TextBox and grab the text from the TextBox
        string myText = ((TextBox)dgMeanings.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(dgMeanings.SelectedCells[0].Item)).SelectedText;

        // Unselect cells to allow for a re-click
        dgMeanings.UnselectAllCells();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

Add `SelectedCellsChanged="dgMeanings_Clicked"` to your `DataGrid` definition

Let me know if this doesn't work as expected or if you have any questions